# Cannot resolve symbol Digits.Builder()

Tags: android, twitter-digits

I want to  change the theme of the Digits screen , and also the text on the button that is provided by default.

Comment: If it can't resolve a symbol, then you're missing a library

Answer (score 0):

change the background of the digit whatever color you want set it,same as settextColor like,

```
button.setTextColor(0xff0000);
```

or

```
button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

or

```
button.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

set color to the layout as:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

Comment: i dont want to change the button named use my phone no..I want to change the theme of the screen where user enter there mobile no. and otp

Comment: yes,I have successfully integrate the library,and my app is working well.i am not able to theme the screen that is provided by api